# Does Holo Theme work with custom titlebar?

Tags: android

I've got an application that draws a custom title bar using the following style for the application theme:

```
<style name="App_Theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">30dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/App_TitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

This does not give me the holo theme. So I set the to parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo". This crashes the application with the following error:

E/AndroidRuntime(2048): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Is it disallowed to use custom title bar using:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

Or am I missing something here?

PS:

The code works perfectly fine with the parent set to "Android:Theme".

I'm using API Level 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly for the benefit of future visitors, one cannot use `Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` with `Holo` themes. Setting `android:windowActionBar` is not what I wanted, since I wanted a title bar, although a customized one.

My workaround, was to `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` and add another layout that looked like a titlebar in my activity. That way, I get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 19):

Let your activity use a theme with following attribute:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 4):

mido is correct

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

is the solution when using @android:style/Theme.Holo (default for ICS).

One observation, if you use @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar change it back to the default @android:style/Theme.Holo.