# Android custom theme on 2.3, holo theme on 4.0

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

I read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html but have some issues. For pre-honeycomb I want a custom title, for post-honeycomb I want the default. When I try to run my app on ICS

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
```

If I remove the custom title it works fine on all releases, just without the custom title.

in values-v11 I have themes.xml file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

So my theme document says to use no custom theme basically.

If I remove

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
```

then the theme shows up correctly on ICS.

I cannot imagine that I have to check on coding level what API level I run and either request the window feature or not, that should be handled by the system.

Thanks, A.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit?  Why would you want to be requesting a custom title at all on ics if you're going to use the default title anyway?

Comment: I don't want a custom title on ICS at all. The themes.xml need for ICS I understood I need from the given link. The requestWindowFeature... coding I need only for 2.3 and below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269081/does-holo-theme-work-with-custom-titlebar) question.  I guess the action bar is considered a title feature, so turning it off gets rid of the exception.

I'm still a bit confused by the question though.  You say you want the default title for post-honeycomb, but you can't use a custom title and also use the default actionbar.  If you really want to do what you're asking (custom title for < 3.0, default actionbar for >= 3.0), then you'll need to check Build.VERSION.SDK_INT before calling window.requestFeature etc.  That's how it's done in the [actionBarCompat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) example that does just this sort of thing.

Comment: okay I didn't want to believe that I really have to check the API level I hoped I don't have. I will do it that way. Thanks for the confirmation and for digging out the actionBarCompat example.